# Query different regex strings based with varying number of words

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to get a target filename from a string list with Regex, but with query that doesn't *exactly* match the files.
The files:

- I have a few thousand files. I don't mind about query speed
- can have any case
- could have space, underscores, dashes or dots to break up words
- if the file uses "`-`" to break up the document name from it's source, just ignore the source (anything before the "`-`").
- if the exact terms are contained in a file that has other text in it, disregard this file (like FileList[0] in the example below)

As I will be doing many of these in my java application, I wanted to create a Java function that could handle varying sized input and filename strings.

Example:

```
Query = "microfluidic systems"

FileList[] = {
    "The.Fabrication.of.microfluidic.systems.in.PDMS.pdf",
    "IEEE - microfluidic systems.pdf",
    "microfluidic systems.pdf",
    "Self-Assembled Electrical Contact to Nanoparticles.pdf",
    "IEEE - Gallium Alloy as Lubricant_for_High_Current - Density Brushes.pdf",
    "Liquid Metal Marbles.pdf"
}
```

Here the second and third file should match the query.

Is this too difficult to do with regex? Or is it just that I will have to create case statements for each regex per the amount of words that are being used in my queries?

**EDIT**
From QPaysTaxes's answer.

```
    String yourText = "microfluidic systems";
    String fileName = "sometext microfluidic systems.pdf";

    String search = yourText.replace(" ", "[\\s_.-]+").toLowerCase();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*" + search + "\\..+$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName.toLowerCase());
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Prints the result:

```
 microfluidic systems.pdf
```

I think I might be missing something?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why do we disregard the first file but not the second one?

Comment: Are you saying that the string you will be matching should always be preceded by ` - `?

Comment: Fixed question up a little. The first file is disregarded because the text was 'contained' in it (ignoring the file extension and the source), rather than equaling it. The string 'can' also be proceeded by the " - ". Anything before this should be ignored.

Comment: @Larry What have you tried so far? Also, please clarify if the regex should ignore file extensions or not, and if so, what file extensions are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should work:

```
-\s*(your text here)\..+$
```

Note that Java requires you to escape your backslashes, so your code will have something like this:

```
String regex = "-\\s*" + yourText + "\\..+$"
```

If you want any kind of space separating the words within your phrase to be accepted, you can replace `yourText` with `yourText.replace(" ", "[\\s_.-]+")` and use spaces in your name definition.

Then, to see if the regex matches the filename, use [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
filename.matches(regex);
```

If you want it to be case-insensitive, convert both to lowercase (i.e. [`String#toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())):

```
fileName.toLowerCase().matches(regex.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Definitely put me on the right path! Only thing, if the search query is contained in a filename at the end, it still shows as a result. E.g. from the example above: Query = "microfluidic systems". Filename = "sometext microfluidic systems.pdf" is still a result.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It should be only a dash, then some spacer characters, then the query text, then the file extension. Lemme test it a little and I'll edit in a corrected version. EDIT: Tested, and it seems to work as advertised -- `sometext microfluidic systems.pdf` isn't matched. However, I did notice that you want the words to be potentially seperated by a space, `-`, `_`, or `.`, so I'm adding that in now. Lemme know if I misunderstood that.

Comment: Please see my questions edit for example code from your answer that still gets that result. Did I implement it correctly?

Comment: @Larry Well, I suggested using `String#matches()`, which is honestly much simpler. Could you try that? (don't worry about putting the code into your question, by the way; your question is starting to diverge from what it was)

Comment: Yes it did! String.Matches() was definitely the thing I was looking for! What you did by replacing the space with the optional characters was the issue I didn't know how to solve originally as well.